# Can we generate BCrypt / SCrypt / Argon2 hash password using CNG (Windows Cryptography API)?

Tags: windows, winapi, cryptography, bcrypt, cryptoapi

Is it possible with the CNG (Windows Cryptography API: Next Generation) to generate BCrypt / SCrypt / Argon2 hash password ?

> BCrypt is a computationally difficult algorithm designed to store
> passwords by way of a one-way hashing function. You input your
> password to the algorithm and after significant (relative)
> computation, an output is produced. Bcrypt has been around since the
> late 90s and has handled significant scrutiny by the information
> security/cryptography community. It has proven reliable and secure
> over time.
>
> Scrypt is an update to the same model from which Bcrypt arose. Scrypt
> is designed so as to rely on high memory requirements as opposed to
> high requirements on computational power. The realization that lead to
> this, was that specialized computer chips (FPGA/ASICs/GPUs) could be
> purchased at scale by an attacker easier than could huge amounts of
> memory for a traditional computer.

Comment: i be say that question unclear now.

Comment: @RbMm, hmm what is unclear in the question ? maybe I didn't ask correctly ?

Comment: @RbMm I have just updated the question

Comment: what is *hash password* ? hash of password ? but with `BCryptHashData` we can easy hash any data. or what you need todo ?

Comment: Not as of today, list is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-algorithm-identifiers but you can register your own provider and use CNG infrastructure (depends on your need and context)

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks, so how with Windows Cryptography API can we do to store hash of password ?

Comment: *store hash of password* ? again unclear. we can simply calculate hash from any data. how store generated hash - is your task. and what data is hashed - again no matter

Comment: @RbMm the idea is that you can not store easy hash of password (like md5, sha1, etc) but you must only store hash that are very hard to produce. https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/12/15/yahoo-breach-ive-closed-my-account-because-it-uses-md5-to-hash-my-password/  question is how to produce such "hash" so that we can store them

Comment: exist list of supported algorithms. you can select any from it.

Comment: With CNG sample is here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Security/KeyDerivation BCRYPT_SP800108_CTR_HMAC_ALGORITHM,    BCRYPT_SP80056A_CONCAT_ALGORITHM, BCRYPT_PBKDF2_ALGORITHM,    BCRYPT_CAPI_KDF_ALGORITHM,

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't think in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Security/KeyDerivation they speak about bcrypt like the algo to hash password with CPU power intensive. I think microsoft use the name BCrypt for another concept

Comment: Absolutely (and yes this is confusing), but CNG does support some KDF (and hashes of course), PBKDF2 (BCRYPT_PBKDF2_ALGORITHM) would be the obvious choice if you don't have BCrypt, Scrypt or Argon2

Comment: @SimonMourier yes but I read that PBKDF2 is definitively a no go :(

Comment: Well this is all you get with standard winapi but you can write your own argon2 code, it's open source.

Comment: @SimonMourier You answer my question :) sad their is no solution but thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

No.

### Long Answer

Neither CryptoAPI nor Crypto API Next Generation (CryptNG) support `bcrypt`, `scrypt`, or `argon2`

bcrypt is a customized version of the **blowfish** encryption algorithm. Blowfish is not supported by CNG. And even if it was, bcrypt uses a version of bcrypt with a custom *"expensive"* key setup.

scrypt is (nearly) PBKDF2, which **is** supported by CNG:

```
Byte[] scrypt(String password, int DesiredNumberOfBytes, ...)
{
   Byte[] salt = SpecialScryptSaltGeneration(password, ...)
   
   return PBKDF2(password, salt, DesiredNumberOfBytes, 1);
}
```

but the **SpecialScryptSaltGenration** uses primitives not included in CNG (ChaCha, Salsa/20).

Argon2 uses custom primitives that don't exist anywhere.